# Definition of a recursive query in SPARQL

Tags: recursion, sparql, rdf, semantic-web

Can we call the below query a recursive query? if not, what can we call it?

```
select ?x ?y 
where{
?x p1* ?y
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [property path](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) operators, such as `*`, offer a limited recursion in SPARQL. However, note that variables are not allowed in property paths, so your query is syntactically invalid.

Comment: Thanks I meant p1* (not ?p1*)